# Unity container object resolution hierarchy

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, containers

I have my container configured like following:

```
container = new UnityContainer()
            .RegisterType<IA, A>()
            .RegisterType<IB, B>()
            .RegisterType<IC, C>(new InjectionConstructor(strA));
```

What I need is, I want to register another C instance like:

```
container.RegisterType<IC, C>(new InjectionConstructor(strB));
```

note the difference between strA and strB.

Both A and B need C. But I want A to use the first C and B to use the second C.

Is there a proper way in Unity to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: At a first glance it appears that strA and strB should be a property on A and B and passed to / evaluated by C.

Comment: I like that. This should be the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use a [named type registration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660923%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx#registertype_simple).

```
var container = new UnityContainer()
  .RegisterType<IC, C>("ForA", new InjectionConstructor(strA))
  .RegisterType<IC, C>("ForB", new InjectionConstructor(strB))

  .RegisterType<IA, A>(new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<IC>("ForA")))
  .RegisterType<IB, B>(new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<IC>("ForB")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've accomplished this in the past by decorating/facading the common interfaces in order to identify them for mappings.

```
// new interface just for A
public interface ICforA : IC { }

// new interface just for B
public interface ICforB : IC { }

container = new UnityContainer()
           .RegisterType<IA, A>()
           .RegisterType<IB, B>()
           .RegisterType<ICforA, C>(new InjectionConstructor(strA));
           .RegisterType<ICforB, C>(new InjectionConstructor(strB));
```

*Disclaimer:  Code written from memory, not Visual Studio.*